# How to break up a jQuery "toggle" function into seperate "show" and "hide" functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a function that toggles the width of a div, so it has the appearence of "sliding in" from outside the boundaries of the screen

```
$(".slider").animate({
  width: "toggle",
}, 300, function() {
});
```

Is there a way I can break this into two different functions, one that shows the div and one that hides it?

So ideally if I trigger the `show` function when the div is already shown, nothing should happen, and vice versa.

I made a fiddle to illustrate what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/2x816nmf/1/ . So the problem in the fiddle is that both `.hide-slider` and `.show-slider` simply toggle the width. `.hide-slider` should *only* set `.slider's` width to 0, and `.show-slider` should *only* set the width to the number defined in the CSS. If I press either button twice in a row, nothing should happen.

Comment: can you please add working fiddle ?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what `break in 2 functions` means and expected behaviors

Comment: @charlietfl I added a fiddle, I hope it explains the whole thing better. I want one function to set the width to 0, and one function that resets the width to however it is defined in the css.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2x816nmf/34/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a boolean variable that checks everything:

```
show = true;

$('.show-slider').click(function() {
    if(show == false){
  $(".slider").animate({
    width: "toggle",
  }, 300, function() {
  });
     show = true;
   }
});
$('.hide-slider').click(function() {
    if (show == true){
  $(".slider").animate({
    width: "toggle",
  }, 300, function() {
  });
        show = false;
    }
});
```

the show variable is first setted to true because the div is visible on start...

change your fiddle and it will work!

Comment: This is a great solution, but I'm actually triggering the functions via ajax requests, which use separate js files. The variable wouldn't retain its value throughout the ajax requests right?

Comment: This tooked me a while, but you should check this fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/2x816nmf/31/ 

feel free to ask for more explanation